# Cyclic dependency in Visitor Design Pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

Is there a way to implement visitor design pattern without cyclic dependency? What I mean is that the visitor need an object to visit. and the visited object needs a visitor to accept. In the end both depend on each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it again! Check out the [Acyclic Visitor](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/acv.pdf):

Quote:

> Allow new functions to be added to existing class hierarchies without
>   affecting those hierarchies, and without creating the troublesome
>   dependency cycles that are inherent to the GOF VISITOR Pattern.

Comment: dead link. Links should be avoided.